# fatal error mysql and login form

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, execution-time

i'm try to let this page works.
it's a login page in HTML and CSS.
here is the code, but when i try to run it, it says

> "Fatal error, maximum of 30 seconds exceeded.... on line 29"

```
<?
$DBhost = "localhost";
$DBuser = "bestparty";
$DBpass = "";
$DBName = "my_bestparty";


$usr = $_POST['Username'];
$pwd = $_POST["Password"];


    mysql_connect($DBhost,$DBuser,$DBpass) or die("Impossibile collegarsi al server");
    @mysql_select_db("$DBName") or die("Impossibile connettersi al database $DBName");



$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM `Utenti`";
$result = mysql_query($sqlquery);
$number = mysql_num_rows($result);

$i = 0;

while ($i < $number) {

      $username[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"username");
      $password[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"password");



}
  if ($username[$i] == $usr && $password[$i] == $pwd) {
            echo"NELLA";
      }
      else {
          echo" ERRORE ";
      }

?>
```

Comment: Note that PHP's mysql_ API is long since deprecated

Answer (score 2):

You never increment `$i` so you have an endless loop as `$i` will *always* be less than `$number`. You also need to move your if/else statement into your while loop.

```
while ($i < $number) {
    $username[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"username");
    $password[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"password");
    // Move this block into your while loop
    if ($username[$i] == $usr && $password[$i] == $pwd) {
        echo"NELLA";
    }
    else {
        echo" ERRORE ";
    }
    $i++; // <-- ADD THIS
}
```